# How to initialize a struct array in a MFC program?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, mfc

I define a struct in the header file and then define the sturct array in the source file, but it shows "no available member" when I call the array member, what should I do? It works well in the win32 console program, but it just doesn't work in the MFC program!
Here are the source code, waitting for your help!

```
typedef struct SMatchItem
{
    CString matchSymbol;
    CString matchDisplay;
    int value;
};

SMatchItem matchItem[] = 
{
    {_T("="), _T("Equal"), 1},
    {_T("!="), _T("Not Equal"), 2},
    {_T("<"), _T("Smaller Than"), 4},
    {_T(">"), _T("Larger Than"), 8},
};
```

when I call this "matchItem[0]." it report an error"no available member!"

Comment: Please post the source code as well.

Comment: OK, I have post my code, thank you for your help.

Comment: It's hard to tell, can you also post the part of the code where you are actually accessing that item?

Comment: I didn't use is actually now, I just want to test it.

Comment: I just access it under the define of the array "matchItem[]".

Comment: Is this a compiler error you're getting when you build?  Or are you saying that auto-complete isn't working in your chosen IDE?

Comment: It's a complier error, there are the auto-complete with the same code in win32 console program.

Comment: First, a problem with the auto-complete function is not a compiler error. Second, your code works fine for me in VS2012. The compiler just warns me that the `typedef` is ignored. I called `TRACE3("%s, %s, %d", matchItem[0].matchSymbol, matchItem[0].matchDisplay, matchItem[0].value);` in the main function after your code and I get the expected result.

Comment: "no available member!", Is it actually a compiler error? I've doubt. However,  your codes works fine in VS2008. The Compiler just warns about the `typedef`.

Comment: I got it, I didn't call it in any function, I just used it in a global area. It works now, thank you for your help!!!